# Junit unable to load properties file of web aplicaion

Tags: unit-testing, web-applications, properties, junit, loading

I have piece of code in webapp which loads a file from WEB-INF classes folder
ex-

```
PropertiesHelper.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/test.properties);
```

I am writing a junit for the above method, but when test is executed it is unable to find/load properties file. I have added the properties file in test resources but still it is unable to load it.
If I change the main code and remove slash - '/', then junit works but code will not work when deployed in webapp.

**How to write junit for the above case?**

Comment: Still have not got any answer how to load properties file if above cod e is used in junit or standalone application (instead of webapp).

Comment: You have to provide a test.properties file on the classpath that is used by the test's classloader.